# Merge ascii files in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, esri-ascii-raster

I have multiple .asc grid files, I need to merge these into one raster grid file.

I would like to know the procedure to merge .asc files.

Comment: You will need to convert them into rasters first.

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert your .ascii to a raster by using the the [ASCII To Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000002s000000) GP tool.
2. Merge multiple rasters with the [raster calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000z7000000) (Spatial Analyst).

Comment: can explain about Merge multiple rasters with the raster calculator

Comment: Use mosaic into new raster

Comment: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/42440 and http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000098000000